# Compilation error after upgrading to Realm 0.92.2

Tags: ios, swift, realm

After updating to Realm 0.92.2, this code is not compiling anymore:

```
let defaultRealm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
let results = OrderModel.allObjectsInRealm(defaultRealm)
if results.count > 0 {
  for row in results {
      self.orders.append(row as! OrderModel)
  }
}
```

The error occurs at line4 and it says :

> Type 'RLMResults' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that 0.92.2 is a pretty big update (for the Swift side of things).
The install is different. Delete Realm.framework from your project and add RealmSwift.framework instead. Follow all the rest of instructions at : 
http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Here are some of the significant changes you need to make in your code:

instead of

```
import Realm
```

do

```
import RealmSwift
```

instead of

```
class OrderModel: RLMObject {
```

do

```
class OrderModel: Object {
```

The code from my original post

```
let defaultRealm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
let results = OrderModel.allObjectsInRealm(defaultRealm)
if results.count > 0 {
  for row in results {
      self.orders.append(row as! OrderModel)
  }
}
```

becomes

```
let results = Realm().objects(OrderModel)
if results.count > 0 {
    for row in results {
        self.orders.append(row)
    }
}
```

Comment: (I work at Realm) Nice answer! We'd like to publish a guide to help users moving from Realm Objective-C to Realm Swift at some point.